# Unexplained StreamLimitationException thrown on Android with Deezer SDK

Tags: android, deezer

I'm using the Deezer Android SDK.  To first order I have things working, but occasionally it throws a "StreamLimitationException" with the explanation that the Deezer account is being used on another device.  However, I know that the account is not being used on another device -- not on a mobile device, and not in a browser.  I even changed the account password to make sure nobody else was using it.

I'm using the TrackPlayer.  I've found that if I try to re-use the same track player for multiple songs, it doesn't work.  So every time I want to play a new song, I call the stop() and then release() methods on the existing TrackPlayer, then obtain a new one.

The exception is thrown sometimes when I try to start playback on a new song.  It appears random to me, in that I'm not aware of any fixed timeout with respect to the time the the DeezerConnect object was authorized.  Furthermore, I'm trying to minimize the possibility of a timeout -- I've used both:

```
deezerConnect.setAccessExpires(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

and

```
deezerConnect.setAccessExpires(0);
```

with no luck.

Additionally, I've tried periodically re-authorizing my deezerConnect object every few minutes, but that hasn't worked.

As one final attempt, I went into my account on the Deezer web site and deleted everything on the "My Apps" page.  Then I re-enabled the app I'm working on.  But I still hit the exception.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to eliminate this problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this issue also happens when using a PlaylistPlayer for  instance ? Both are build in the same way, and the player is not released between tracks.

Comment: With either TrackPlayer or PlaylistPlayer, after a while when I call deezerConnector.isSessionValid() I get "false".  If I'm using TrackPlayer, subsequent attempts to get a new player and play tracks result in a StreamLimitationError.  When I'm using PlaylistPlayer, it continues to play the playlist (since I'm not trying to get a new player instance).

Comment: I am having the same issues on my app. This was not a problem on the beginning, but after I added additional code (serial port). I get this error quite often. Did you figure out what was causing it?

Comment: Unfortunately no -- I still have this problem. I'm not using a serial port (and I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that) but I am using a variety of Android resources for the app, including some other modules that use WiFi. I suppose I could try eliminating other functions to see if that has any effect, but ultimately I do need it all to work together. Please let us know if you come up with anything!

Comment: Interesting. I also "removed" all my associated devices except for one. I say "removed" as they actualy stayed on the list, but after a while the official app stopped throwing exceptions and behaved as it is supposed to. The app I'm trying to write sadly still doesnt behave as expected. At least not on all HW platforms I tested. I will let you know if anything pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be an easy fix.  DeezerConnect.authorize() takes a "permissions" argument.  I changed mine from

```
    final String[] permissions = new String[] {
            Permissions.BASIC_ACCESS
    };
```

to

```
    final String[] permissions = new String[] {
            Permissions.BASIC_ACCESS,
            Permissions.OFFLINE_ACCESS // For no timeout
    };
```

As documented at https://developers.deezer.com/api/oauth.

Problem solved!